# How is "this" used when it comes after a Class like this?

Tags: java, this

I don't quite understand how the keyword `this` is being used in this instance.

```
private void checkForComodification() {
    // The this I'm concerned about is the first one
    if (CyclicArrayList.this.modCount != this.modCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need this sometimes in inner classes.

`this` points to the inner class instance itself.

`MyOuterClass.this` points to the containing class instance.

In your case, this is necessary, because both classes have a `modCount` property (and the one from the outer class `CyclicArrayList` is shadowed here).

Comment: Inner class as in? There isn't any other class inside this class, and it doesn't extend/implement anything.

Comment: The code looks like it is an inner class (implementing maybe an Iterator or a sublist) contained in CyclicArrayList.

Comment: Nope. I saw that java.util.ArrayList used that to determine concurrent modification, so I copied it. I see now. There is literally no point in copying this, is there? And yes, the ArrayList one does happen to be inside an inner class.

Answer (score 3):

It is used for inner classes where you want a attribute or method in the "outer" scope which has the same name as one in your current class.

By default the 'this' keyword refers to the current class scope, without this feature you'd have no access to outer fields and methods with the same name.

```
public class Outer {
  private String test = "outer;
  private class Inner {
    private String test = "inner";
    public void foo() {
       System.out.println(this.test);       // "inner"
       System.out.println(Outer.this.test); // "outer"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that even by default, you can get to the outer field/method, as long as the names don't collide.